# Как сделать, чтобы при наведении курсора на фотку она покрылась прозрачно-черным цветом?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать, чтобы при наведении курсора на фотку она покрылась прозрачно-черным цветом?

Нет, я не нуб. Сделал так:

```
<div id="grid">
    <div id="cover">
    <img src="img/albums.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img {
height:200px;
width:200px;
z-index:5;
    }

#grid {
height:200px;
width:500px;
z-index:4;
background-color:#499;
}

#grid:hover img {
background-color:rgba(0,0,0, 0.6);
z-index:6;
}
```

Вот тут он работает как надо: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PdCYM/)

Думаю проблема в том, что это прозрачное покрытие не может ставать перед фоткой. В JSFiddle т.к не отображается фотка, то покрытие сползает. А когда там фотка стоит, то она не позволяет background-color сползать поверх.

Как решить проблему?

Comment: @navi1893, http://jsfiddle.net/yU587/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может, как-то так?

HTML:

```
<div id="grid">
    <img src="img/albums.jpg" />
    <div id="cover"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img, #cover {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
}
#grid {
    height:200px;
    width:500px;
    background-color:#499;
}
#grid:hover #cover {
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0, 0.6);
}
```

Comment: а зачем вы убрали з-индексы и позицию на абсолют сделали???

Comment: А для чего они вообще были нужны? `position:absolute;` - чтобы `div` был над `img`.

Comment: у меня, когда вывожу <img> наверх проблемы возникают. По другому как можно добиться?

Comment: @navi1893, какие именно проблемы?

Comment: Судя по id="grid", вы пытаетесь сделать сетку из таких рисунков? http://jsfiddle.net/GoodBadMan/TdQdr/